# Kestrel HTTPS POST results in a 400 bad request status code when in production (ASP.NET Core 2.x)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I followed this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl

Where I setup exactly as the article suggests

```
// Requires using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
    });
```

and

```
// Requires using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite;
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    var options = new RewriteOptions()
       .AddRedirectToHttps();

    app.UseRewriter(options);
```

This seems to work fine when sending a GET request on all browsers. However, when it hits a POST request, I get a 400 status code without much indication of what is causing it -- oddly, this problem does not happen in DEBUG mode.

If I use Edge or IE, this error does not happen. When I use Chrome or POSTMAN, I get the 400 status code.

Oddly, if I use POSTMAN, and I change the POST request to use HTTP, instead of HTTPS I get the 200 (OK) response. So, I am thinking there is some kind of problem with the article above, but I haven't had much luck with the solution.

Anyone have any experience or insight for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I never worked with ASP.NET Core rewriter, but looking into its code, it uses standard `Response.Redirect()` method -                 https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/blob/9814f3bfbcf3a11dc86c4047fbfc2fe48744f96c/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite/Internal/RedirectToHttpsRule.cs#L33

This Redirect() method is capable of returning HTTP 301 or 302 codes only.
The browser will most likely follow this redirect, but it might decide to use GET or POST without any data.
I recommend enabling `preserve log` in your browser dev tools and checking what is actually happening. This post describes it very well - https://scotthelme.co.uk/report-uri-journey-to-a-permanent-redirect/

Long story short, you need HTTP 307 or 308. `AddRedirectToHttps` has an optional status code argument, which is not used anywhere in code(looks like a bug on ASP.NET Core)

You will probably have to write your own code to redirect HTTP requests.

I had the same problem in one my projects and for a simplicity I decided to return HTTP 403 Forbidden for non-GET HTTP requests

**EDIT:**

I looked into wrong branch of `AddRedirectToHttps`. Actually it seems to be capable of returning different status codes then just 301 and 302, so you should be able to easily configure the status code as an argument.